# mustache js : is it possible to have mustache render html that is within the json object being passed in?

Tags: javascript, json, mustache

Is it possible to have mustache render html that is within the json object being passed in?  Here is an example :

**json object**

```
{
    message : "Hello World! <em>How are you?</em>"
}
```

**template**

```
<p>{{message}}</p>
```

**current output**

Hello World! <em>How are you?</em>

**desired output**

Hello World! **How are you?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior is to escape all variables in Mustache. But you can do unescaped HTML like this `{{{ message }}}`.

See http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'triple mustache', i.e. `{{{message}}}` instead of `{{message}}`. The extra brace overrides Mustache.js' default escaping.

If your mustache.js is relatively recent, you should also be able to use `&` to unescape a value, i.e. `{{&message}}`.